# How to send a UIWebView's URL over email

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I would like to know how to send the webview link via email. Then when the recipient gets the email they can open the link in safari. Thanks in advance!

I put this BOOL in my delegate

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqual:@"mailto"]) { 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]]; return NO; 
} 
return YES; 
}

MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; 
[composer setMailComposeDelegate:self]; 
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) { 
    [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil]];
    [composer setSubject:@""]; 
    [composer setMessageBody:webview isHTML:YES]; 
    [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve]; 
    [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
    [composer release];
}
```

Comment: - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqual:@"mailto"]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

Comment: MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            [composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
            if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
                [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil]];
                [composer setSubject:@""];
                [composer setMessageBody:webview.self isHTML:YES];
                [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
                [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
                [composer release];

Comment: @bryanmac i put the (BOOL) in my delegate.

Comment: Please edit the post and show some code - that will enable others to help ...

Comment: That 'BOOL' is called a *method...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
        if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
            [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil]];
            [composer setSubject:@""];
            [composer setMessageBody:webview.request.URL.absoluteString isHTML:YES];
            [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
            [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
            [composer release];
        }
        else
            [composer release];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You are doing two different things in your listing:**

- If you want to show a `MFMailComposeViewController` upon tap on a `mailto:` link in your webview, the first part of your code (in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`) should work except you will have to change `isEqual` to `isEqualToString`:

  ```
  - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqualToString:@"mailto"]) {  //Change in this line
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]]; return NO; 
    } 
    return YES; 
  }
  ```

  (Note that the user will leave your app when using this)
- If you want to send the link the user tapped to someone, you could use something like

  ```
  -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

  MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; 
  [composer setMailComposeDelegate:self]; 
  if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) { 
      [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil]];
      [composer setSubject:@"Link"]; 
      [composer setMessageBody:request.URL isHTML:YES]; 
      [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve]; 
      [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
      [composer release];
  }

  return YES; 
  }
  ```

Comment: The mailto: is what i want but didn't understand what you meant. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I am new to this could you explain/show what I would need to do. Thanks!!

Comment: I've added a listing and marked the line containing the text you have to change

Comment: Sorry it was my fault: Of course it must be isEqualToString. Just copy the first of my listings.